# Why are my js files being loaded as `index.html` instead of the actual js files created by webpack?

Tags: express, webpack

I'm creating a simple build from webpack, using typescript, jade, and stylus. When the final `index.html` file is spit out, however, it seems to think the `js` files are just the `index.html` file and not the actual `js` files bundled up by webpack and dynamically inserted at the bottom of the `html body`.

My project directory structure looks like this:

```
- dist (compiled/transpiled files)
  - server
    - dependencies
    - index.js
    - app.js
  - app.[hash].js
  - polyfills.[hash].js
- node_modules
- src
  - server
    - dependencies
    - index.ts
    - app.ts
  - client (ng2 ts files)
  - index.jade
```

This is my webpack build:

```js
'use strict';
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');
const rootDir = __dirname;
/**
 * Resolve paths so that we don't have to use relative paths when importing dependencies.
 * Very helpful when scaling an application and changing the location of a file that my require another file
 * in the same directory as the one it used to be in
 */
const pathResolves = [path.resolve(rootDir, 'src'), path.resolve(rootDir, 'node_modules')];
console.log('path', path.resolve(rootDir, 'src/server'));
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'app': path.resolve(rootDir, 'src/client/main.ts'),
    'polyfills': [
      'core-js/es6',
      'core-js/es7/reflect',
      'zone.js/dist/zone'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(rootDir, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].[hash].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.component.ts$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'angular2-template-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              configFileName: path.resolve(rootDir, 'tsconfig.client.json')
            }
          }],
        include: [path.resolve(rootDir, 'src/client')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              configFileName: path.resolve(rootDir, 'tsconfig.client.json')
            }
          }
        ],
        exclude: /\.component.ts$/
      },
      {
        test: /\.jade$/,
        use: ['pug-ng-html-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'raw-loader' },
          { loader: 'stylus-loader' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.jade', '.styl'],
    modules: pathResolves
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'polyfills'
    }),
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(rootDir, 'dist/index.html')
    }),

    /**
     * Define any environment variables for client
     */
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      APP_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.APP_ENVIRONMENT || 'development')
    }),
    /**
     * This plugin is required because webpack 2.0 has some issues compiling angular 2.
     * The angular CLI team implemented this quick regexp fix to get around compilation errors
     */
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
      './'
    )
  ]
};
```

And finally, this is the `src/server/app.ts` file that serves up `index.html`:

```js
import * as express from 'express';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as morgan from 'morgan';
import {
  Config
}
from './dependencies/config';

export
function app(Container) {
  const app = express();

  const config: Config = Container.get(Config);
  if (config.log.dev) {
    app.use(morgan('combined'));
  }

  app.get('/', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    const indexPath: string = `dist/index.html`;
    const encodeType: string = `utf-8`;
    const html = fs.readFile(indexPath, encodeType, (err: Error, result: string) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json(err);
      }

      return res.send(result);
    });
  });

  return app;
}
```

The browser console shows the following 404 error messages (they're red in the browser console) when i go to `localhost:3000`:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/polyfills.9dcbd04127bb957ccf5e.js
GET http://localhost:3000/app.9dcbd04127bb957ccf5e.js
```

I know it's supposed to be getting the js files from `dist/[file].[hash].js`, but can't seem to make it work with webpack. Also, I should note that I set `NODE_PATH` to `./` in my gulp nodemon config. Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: What errors? I only see two GET requests.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to clarify that they are 404 messages. I edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: Sigh, I'm an idiot... I forgot to put in the `express.static('dist')`. Idk why i always forget to do that when i start up a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out on my own. Forgot to add `app.use(express.static('dist'))` middleware to the `app.ts` file.

Comment: Instead of writing your own server code, you can also use `webpack-dev-server` by adding a few lines to the config. Hell, it even throws in live-reloading for free.